# SSL error when trying to connect to real service

Tags: rust, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, actix-web

I want to create simple HTTPS server in Actix-Web using [this tutorial](https://actix.rs/docs/http2/)
When using self-singned TLS keys created by openssl like in tutorial, everything works fine at localhost.
But when I try to load real keys from, i.e ZeroSSL, browser can't open my service with ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH for Chrome-based and SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP for Mozilla.

```
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let cert_key_file: PathBuf = PathBuf::from("zerossl/private.key");
    let cert_file: PathBuf = PathBuf::from("zerossl/certificate.crt");
    let cert_ca_file: PathBuf = PathBuf::from("zerossl/ca_bundle.crt");
    // To be shorter I omitted creation of paths: path_to_certificate, path_to_ca, path_to_key

    let mut local_address = format!("0.0.0.0:{}", SERVICE_PORT);
    let mut builder = SslAcceptor::mozilla_intermediate(SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
    builder
        .set_private_key_file(path_to_key, SslFiletype::PEM)
        .unwrap();
    builder.set_certificate_chain_file(path_to_ca).unwrap();
    builder.set_certificate_file(path_to_certificate, SslFiletype::PEM).unwrap();

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            //.route("/{filename:.*}", web::get().to(index))
            .route("/hello", web::get().to(|| async { "Hello World!" }))
            .service(greet)
    })
    .bind_openssl(local_address, builder)?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Upd. Added curl info

```
➜  release git:(master) curl -v https://zavijavasoft.com:8080
*   Trying 37.140.197.152:8080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to zavijavasoft.com (37.140.197.152) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: Are you accessing your server through a public URL with a valid DNS entry? You can't just `https://127.0.0.1` with an official certificate, they are connected to your real, public address. Of course that's just a guess, there are a bunch of debugging details missing in your question.

Comment: Otherwise, try to access it with `curl -v https://<url>` and show the error message here, your error descriptions are not detailed enough.

Comment: Added curl description

Comment: Do you get any log messages while connecting?

Comment: No... no messages in std or stderr

Comment: Did you attach a logger? https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/middleware/struct.Logger.html I don't think actix-web logs by default

Comment: Also, try to attach it to port `443` and test it with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: No additonal info by logger
[2022-09-15T16:21:01Z INFO  actix_server::builder] Starting 6 workers
[2022-09-15T16:21:01Z INFO  actix_server::server] Actix runtime found; starting in Actix runtime

Comment: ssllabs.com/ssltest : Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server

Comment: Hmmm ... running out of ideas. Might require an expert